# Laravel - 2 forms on single page

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have 2 forms placed in single view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'MyController@verifyChangelogin')) }}

{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'MyController@verifyCreatelogin')) }}
```

I also have 2 post routes with defined controller methods:

```
Route::post('changelogin', array('uses' => 'MyController@verifyChangeLogin', 'before' => 'auth'));

Route::post('createlogin', array('uses' => 'MyController@verifyCreateLogin', 'before' => 'auth'));
```

Problem is that when I click on submit button of the second form, it calls wrong Route, allways 'changelogin' instead of 'createlogin'.

I have studied another simmilar posts on stackoverflow, but none of the solutions worked for me. Cant find out what's wrong here. What could I do with that?

Answer (score 2):

Are you definitely closing the first form before you open the second?

```
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: indeed, open pairs with close :)